# Flutter : button won't invoke function without a second click

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I have an elevated button which is used for sign in, and it won't do anything till I press the button again, I don't know what Iam doing wrong! , I have never encountered such an issue! , I want to know what the problem is and what caused it .

here is the button code :

**code :**

```
onPressed: () async {
                                  print("pressed");

                                  if (formKey.value.currentState!.validate()) {
                                    ref
                                        .read(
                                            signInWithEmailAndPasswordUseCaseProvider)
                                        .execute(
                                            SignInWithEmailAndPasswordUseCaseInput(
                                                email: patient.value.email,
                                                password: password.text))
                                        .then((value) => value.fold((l) {
                                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                                  .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                                      duration: const Duration(
                                                          seconds: 3),
                                                      content: Text(l
                                                                  .toString() ==
                                                              "ApiFailures.authFailed()"
                                                          ? "Please check your email and password again"
                                                          : l.toString() ==
                                                                  "ApiFailures.noConnection()"
                                                              ? "Please check your internet connection"
                                                              : "pleaase contact us")));
                                            }, (r)  {
                                              if (r.account_type == "Doctors") {
                                                context.router.replaceAll([
                                                  const DoctorPanelScreen()
                                                ]);
                                              } else {
                                                token1.value = r.api_token!;

                                                data.when(
                                                    data: (data) {
                                                      data.fold(
                                                          (l) => print("helo1"),
                                                          (r) async {
                                                        print(r);
                                                        docid.value = r.id!;
                                                        patient.value = patient
                                                            .value
                                                            .copyWith(
                                                                name: r.name,
                                                                aliid: r.id,
                                                                appointments: r
                                                                    .patient_appointments,
                                                                fcmtoken:
                                                                     token);
                                                        print(patient.value);
                                                        doc.maybeWhen(
                                                            orElse: () => print(
                                                                "getpatienterror"),
                                                            data: (data) {
                                                              print(data);
                                                              if (data
                                                                  .isEmpty) {
                                                               ref
                                                                    .read(
                                                                        firebasesignUpWithEmailAndPasswordUseCaseProvider)
                                                                    .execute(
                                                                        FirebaseSignUpWithEmailAndPasswordUseCaseInput(
                                                                      user: patient
                                                                          .value,
                                                                      password:
                                                                          password
                                                                              .text,
                                                                    ))
                                                                    .then((value) => value.fold(
                                                                        (l) => print(l
                                                                            .toString()),
                                                                        (r) => print(
                                                                            "done")
                                                                        // context.router.replaceAll([
                                                                        //   const HomeScreen()
                                                                        // ])
                                                                        ));
                                                              } else {
                                                                print(
                                                                    "firebased");
                                                                context.router
                                                                    .replaceAll([
                                                                  const HomeScreen()
                                                                ]);
                                                              }
                                                            });
                                                      });
                                                    },
                                                    error: (error, _) {},
                                                    loading: () {
                                                      
                                                    });
                                              }
                                            }));
                                  }
                                }
```

it prints `pressed` in the first time, and that's weird, any suggestions ?

Comment: My guess is that your validate returns false the first time, and true the second time. Did you try debugging and seeing what's the difference between the first and second time?

Comment: yes i did , the strange thing that the value of `docid` won't change except in the second time